# Perl strip off quotes and spaces

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I'm trying to push information from file to array.
I have file that looks like this:

```
1.2.3.4      =>  '"Something"'
5.6.7.8      =>  '"One more time"'
```

So the delimiter is `"=>"`. So I try to push information from file to array like this:

```
my $filename = '/root/file';
open(my $filehandle, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open $filename\n";
my @resultarray;
while(my $line = <$filehandle>){
    chomp $line;
    my @linearray = split("=>", $line);
    push(@resultarray, @linearray);
}
```

Then I try to remove whate spaces and quotes:

```
my @stripArray = grep(s/\s*$//g, @resultarray);
my @stripArray = grep(s/([^"]*)//, @stripArray);
print Dumper(@stripArray);
```

But all I get is:

```
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR2 = '"Something"';
$VAR3 = '';
$VAR4 = '"One more time"';
```

So the numbers are missing and the quotes are still there..... Trying to solve this riddle for about 3 hours, so thought it is time to ask for some help.

Comment: `stip` and `strip` are two different names.

Answer (score 2):

[grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) only returns the elements of the list that the expression returned true for. `s///` returns false if there's nothing to substitute, so the numbers aren't returned from `grep`.

Don't use `grep` to change the elements of the list. That's what `map` is for:

```
@stripArray = map s/\s+$//r, @resultarray;
```

You can also include the whitespace to the delimiter so you don't have to remove the spaces later:

```
my @linearray = split /\s*=>\s*/, $line;
```

Comment: So it helped with the whitespaces and numbers, but the quotes is still there.
`my @stripArray = map s/^'([^']*)'$/$1/, @resultarray;`
I try to remove it like this but then whole string vanishes.

Comment: @semikus: You're missing the `/r` part that returns the result of the substitution instead of modifying the string in place.

Answer (score 0):

Input data are very easy to process with regular expression, extract information of interest and put it into array

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @array;

while(<DATA>) {
    my @data = /(\S+)\s+=>\s+"(.*?)"/;
    push @array, \@data;
}

say Dumper(\@array);

__DATA__
1.2.3.4      =>  "Something"
5.6.7.8      =>  "One more time"
```

Or shorted version of same code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @array;

/(\S+)\s+=>\s+"(.*?)"/ && push @array, [$1,$2] while <DATA>;

say Dumper(\@array);

__DATA__
1.2.3.4      =>  "Something"
5.6.7.8      =>  "One more time"
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1.2.3.4',
            'Something'
          ],
          [
            '5.6.7.8',
            'One more time'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: better to more exactly match the example and check for errors: `my @data = /^(\S+)\s+=>\s+"(.*?)"\s*$/ or warn "unexpected input: $_";`

Comment: @ysth -- what if in front of the the first digit will be one or more space characters?

Comment: then add that too.  but just leaving off anchors lets it match all kinds of things that it likely shouldn't

Comment: @ysth -- then files with data should have specification what should be in them. OP did not provide such specification and assumption was that no other data variation form will be present.